# How to Access the VC++ library from ROR?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, visual-c++

i have developed library file in VC++ and need to use same library with Ruby on Rails project also. Is it possible to access VC++ library file from Ruby on rails project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be using [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/About).

Comment: IronRuby runs on .Net, so you could probably somehow use PInvoke.  I suspect the Op would need to research invoking a platform library from Ruby the language/platform itself if they arent running on .net using IronRuby.